# Use Phone for Development

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm in Xcode 6 latest beta and am unsure how to build to my phone. What are the steps necessary? Online seems to mostly have dated articles back when 'organiser' contained the devices tab.

When I go to the devices menu item now, I don't see a checkbox for 'use for development'. My phone is plugged in.

What gives? How can I provision my phone? I just went online, did it the long way (by adding my ID etc) and generated a provisioning file, but now what?

Comment: is your iPhone on iOS8?

Comment: Ah no! I feel stupid. I presume this is why eh? I need to upgrade to ios8 first right? What's the best way to do that?

Comment: download ios8 beta from iOS dev site

Comment: Be careful, not all apps currently work with iOS8.

Comment: hmm.... ok maybe i'll wait then I feel nervous doing this anyway, i'll just continue to develop locally on the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the deploymentTarget to iOS 7.1. You can run your Swift-Code on that iOS as well. Then select your iPhone (right next to run & stop).

There you go.  Hope I could help ;)

Comment: hey so this worked but immediately crashes on a line of code - is it possible swift code would have issues? Specifically it's date = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.DayCalendarUnit, value: 1, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(0))

Comment: glad I could help :)  actually always there can occur an error because Swift and Xcode 6 are still in Beta. I don't really know whether the line is the problem. 1. try to deactivate the line using // in front of it. if the error is still there do the same with different lines that may be insecure. if it still does not help then plug in another iPhone and / or simply run it with the Simulator